# How to mapping value with identifier and variable value in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How to mapping value with identifier and variable value in C#

```
public class Table1
{
     public string FIELD1 { get; set; }
     public string FIELD2 { get; set; }
     public string FIELD3 { get; set; }
}
```

maps FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,...,FIELDxx to class Animal that Name is FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,...,FIELDxx

```
public class Animal
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<Animal> a = new List<Animal>();
a.Add(new Animal(){
     Name = "FIELD1",
     Value = "Elephant"
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an `Animal` for each `FIELD` of `Table1`?

Comment: Reflection would be the easiest option, however this all looks like a nightmare

Comment: @Gildor Absolutely, I'm trying to create FIELD1=>Elephant, FIELD2=>Cat

Comment: @ArnunSae-Lim Please check the answer. However using reflection carefully when performance is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var t = new Table1();

foreach(var animal in a)
{
  t.GetType().GetProperty(animal.Name).SetValue(t, animal.Value);
}
```

Comment: Seems `a` is an empty list and he is trying to create instances.

Comment: he adds an instance of an animal to a, which has a Name which corresponds to a property on table1,  so as an example I take that, and set the value of that property to the animal name

Comment: He can go the other way pretty easy too

Answer (score 1):

C# Dictionary can be used to maintain  collection for this mapping purpose. In dictionary, for the case given,

```
var t = new Table1();
Animal a = new Animal();

Dictionary<string, string> idVarMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
idVarMap.Add(t.FIELD1,a.Value);
```

Then the value can be retrieved as:

```
if (idVarMap.ContainsKey(t.FIELD1))
{
    int value = idVarMap[t.FIELD1];
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Is this way helpful? Or you are looking for other approach?

Answer (score 1):

Keith's answer already shows the direction. Here's the code for your specific question:

```
var t = new Table1() 
{
    FIELD1 = "Elephant",
    FIELD2 = "Cat",
    FIELD3 = "Dog",
};
List<Animal> a = new List<Animal>();

foreach(var prop in t.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("FIELD")))
{
    a.Add(new Animal()
    {
        Name = prop.Name,
        Value = (string)prop.GetValue(t)
    });
}
```